# Calculate the median

Tags: algebra-precalculus

May i ask you to help me on this question?

1) the height in Cm of 10 boys are given below
117, 108, 122, 117, 108, 120, 118, 117, 123, 124

Calculate the median height.

How can i solve this question?

Thanks.

Edit: Thanks but why should I take 5th and 6th term? i don't get this part.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Why should I take 5th and 6th term?

Comment: If you have the feeling that an answer solves your problem, than don't forget to accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median is the middle element of your sorted list respectively for an odd number of elements the average between the two middle elements. Therefore:

108,108,117,117,**117,118**,120,122,123,124

$Median = \large\frac{117+118}{2} \normalsize= 117.5$

Comment: Why should I take 5th and 6th term?

Comment: Because the 5th and 6th elements are in the middle of your list. There are 4 elements in front of them in your sorted list and 4 elements afterwards. There are two middle elements, because the number of elements is odd. 
If the number of elements is even, than you just can take one middle element. For example the 5th element would be in the middle of a list with 9 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Median is the middle value. If we arrange the given heights in increasing order we get:

$108 ,108 ,117 ,117 ,117 ,118 ,120 ,122 ,123 ,124$

We can see there are $10$ values. So there are 2 middle values, the $5$th and the $6$th values. Can you see which are the $5$th and $6$th values in the re arranged list? Can you find their average now?

Read this for more help: [MeanMode](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm)